# how to make 4 matplotlib.pyplot graphs with concrete data from csv file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I am studying python programming courses,
and by the end of the module we were given the following task:

1. Analyze historical data on weather conditions in your city using Python.
2. To do this, you need to download the temperature, wind speed, relative humidity and the atmospheric pressure data and visualize it in the form of informative graphs with signed axes and a clear legend.
   More information about working with a source of meteorological data (website rp5.ru ).
   Indicators and evaluation criteria:
   0 — there are no data for analysis, the analysis has not been carried out.
   1 — weather data has been collected, but has not been preprocessed, analysis has not been carried out.
   2 — data has been collected, preprocessing has been carried out, but not fully visualized or uninformatively.
   3 — data has been collected, preprocessing has been carried out, visualization of graphs of temperature, wind speed and relative humidity has been performed.
   Rating scale:
   The lower value is -0.
   The upper value is -3.
   The minimum passing score is 2.

i can't complete the task and i need help
someone have pity on me and complete this task :(

i tried to display the information from csv on the graph in different ways, but the graphs turned out to be strange and some data could not be displayed

Comment: Please could you: a. provide a [minimal, reproducible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and b. give us some dummy data?

Comment: You should probably show us that you have at least tried to answer the question. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could get inspiration from this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dates = pd.date_range('20220301', periods=100, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datetime': dates,
    'temperature': np.random.randint(-10, 30, size=100),
    'wind_speed': np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=100),
    'relative_humidity': np.random.uniform(20, 80, size=100),
    'atmospheric_pressure': np.random.uniform(980, 1050, size=100),
})


df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(10, 10))

axs[0].plot(df['temperature'])
axs[0].set_ylabel('Temperature (C)')

axs[1].plot(df['wind_speed'])
axs[1].set_ylabel('Wind Speed (m/s)')

axs[2].plot(df['relative_humidity'])
axs[2].set_ylabel('Relative Humidity (%)')

axs[3].plot(df['atmospheric_pressure'])
axs[3].set_ylabel('Atmospheric Pressure (hPa)')

axs[3].set_xlabel('Date')
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

But it would b wise of you to learn these things by reading documentations in the future and not relying on SO for your homework.